# Use input from a custom quasiquoter as actual code

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Lets say I have a custom quasiquote, named xpto:

```
[xtpo|data Something = Abc | Def deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Enum,Bounded)|]
```

I want to actually declare this as it is, but additionally derive some more stuff based on the constructor names. That last part is done (function generateDataDefs, irrelevant here), but I am doing inclusion of the original declaration through [haskell-src-meta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta), which seems like quite an heavy dependency. Like this:

```
xpto = QuasiQuoter { quoteDec = either (const . return $ []) generateDataDefs
                                                           . parseDecs }
```

Can I avoid using [parseDecs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.7/docs/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html#v%3aparseDecs) and just use Template Haskell instead?

PS: the function generateDataDefs takes the received [Dec], and appends the new code to it:

```
generateDataDefs :: [Dec] -> Q [Dec]
generateDataDefs decData = let
(...)
 in return $ decData ++ remainingStuff
```

Comment: You could not use a quasiquoter, and have users write `generateDataDefs =<< [d|data Something = Abc | Def deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Enum,Bounded)|]` instead

Comment: Perfect. Please make that an answer so that I can mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not use a quasiquoter, and have users write

```
    generateDataDefs =<< [d|data Something = Abc
                                        | Def
                              deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Enum,Bounded)|]
```